# How Anomaly Analysis is differentiating from Heuristic analysis

Tags: cissp

Taking a look at the discription of both kinds, orientation seems the same. while it isn't the same I can't figure the difference. In a Heuristic scan it looks for suspicious or malicious behaviors in a file, Anomaly analysis looks for anomalies in a file and its structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for anomaly is look for things that aren't bad *per se*, but usually isn't common. For instance, a freshly registered domain being accessed late night, and receiving lots of traffic. Or your HR computers accessing Github, or executing PowerShell scripts.

Those things are not wrong, they are out of place. Accessing Github is not wrong. But it's strange for certain group of users. In this case, an heuristic scanner would not find anything strange.

On the other hand, an anomaly detector needs a baseline. If you don't have a good baseline, you will either get a lot of false positives, and end up shutting down the scanner, or a lot of false negatives and will not be of any use.

Comment: Great answer. Does a heuristic scanner also needs a good baseline to deal with FP's FN's or is a heuristic scanner by nature more (not fully) resistant to these?

Comment: They need a baseline too, but it's easier to make. Binding a socket to cmd.exe, for example, is almost universally a bad thing. Acessing github? It heavily depends...

Answer (score 1):

It's the difference between "weird" and "bad".

Anomaly analysis looks for the "weird". There is no judgement about whether it is "bad". In a lot of contexts, weird = bad, but not always.

Heuristic analysis learns what is "bad" and looks for that, even if it turns out to be "normal".